# Google Cloud Run fails to listen even after changing port to 8080

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am having some issues deploying to Cloud Run lately. When I am trying to deploy the below Dockerfile to Cloud Run, it ends up with the error **Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable.**:

```
FROM phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest

EXPOSE 8080

RUN sed -i 's/80/${PORT}/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf

ENTRYPOINT [ "/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD [ "apache2-foreground" ]
```

The ENTRYPOINT and CMD were added separately even though the **phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest** uses this same ENTRYPOINT and CMD to see if that would solve it, though it is not required. The same Docker image when deployed using **docker run** runs properly and listens on port 8080. Is there something I am doing wrong?

This is the command I use to deploy:

```
gcloud run deploy phpmyadmin --memory=1Gi --platform=managed \
--allow-unauthenticated --add-cloudsql-instances project_id:us-central1:db-name \ 
--region=us-central1 --image gcr.io/project_id/phpmyadmin:1.3 \
--update-env-vars PMA_HOST=localhost,PMA_SOCKET="/cloudsql/project_id:us-central1:db-name",PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI=phpmyadmin.domain.com
```

This is all I can find in the logs. (Have redacted some data):

https://gist.github.com/shanukk27/9dd4b3076c55307bd6e853a76e7a34e0

Comment: Can you go to the logging page and share the log details? The message that you have is a standard Cloud Run error message. The problem is: Your containter don't start and thus, Cloud Run detect no port opened on 8080, but the port isn't the problem!!

Comment: Didn't share the logs since I couldn't find anything particularly interesting. @guillaumeblaquiere , I have updated the question with the logs.

Comment: Ok, the log simply tell that the healthcheck is KO that's why you have this error. it's "normal". So, what you have a CMD and an ENTRYPOINT in your dockerfile? I never use both, only one of them. I don't know what is ran by Docker Run now! Did you try several different commands?

Comment: I just copied the CMD and ENTRYPOINT from the base image phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest . In fact, I don't even require those two as the image will fetch the ENTRYPOINT from the base image. That is what I tried at first, but failed. @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: And what is the content of the `/docker-entrypoint.sh` file?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - That would be:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phpmyadmin/docker/master/docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214911/discussion-between-shanu-koyakutty-and-guillaume-blaquiere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Run runtime environment seems to be slightly different than Docker run command. You can't use ENTRYPOINT and CMD in the same time

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD [ "apache2-foreground" ]
```

It works with Docker Run (Why? Docker issue? Docker feature?) and not on Cloud Run (missing feature? bug?).

Use only one of them, for example:

```
ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh && apache2-foreground
```

**EDIT**

A strange remark shared by Shanu is the 2 command works with Wordpress deployment, and doesn't work here.

```
FROM wordpress:5.3.2-php7.3-apache

EXPOSE 8080

# Copy custom entrypoint from repo
COPY cloud-run-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

# Change apache listening port and set permission for docker entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/80/${PORT}/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf && \
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cloud-run-entrypoint.sh

# Wordpress conf
COPY wordpress/. /var/www/html/

# Custom entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["cloud-run-entrypoint.sh","docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Start apache when docker container starts
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

The problem is solved here, but the reason is not clear

**Note to Googler (Steren? Ahmet?)**: Can you share more details on this behavior?

Comment: Yeah we'll follow up on our side. There should be no difference on how ENTRYPOINT/CMD is handled when the developer doesn't specify --cmd --args explicitly.

Comment: I actually just deployed with a Go server `ENTRYPOINT ["/server"]` and `CMD ["a","b","c"]` and printed out `os.Args()`, it has successfully printed `[/server a b c]`. I'm suspecting there's an issue with `docker-entrypoint.sh` above.

Comment: That said I found this bug: if you have `ENTRYPOINT ["/server"]` `CMD ["x"]`, and specify `--args=a,b` you actually get `[/server,x,a,b]` but you should be getting `[/server,a,b]`! That's unexpected, we'll fix that!

Comment: @AhmetB-Google, thanks for your investigation and your explanations!!